# The locus of polynomials with specified root multiplicities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $\mathcal{P}_d\cong\mathbb{A}^d$ denote the set of monic degree $d$ polynomials defined over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$, where we identify $f(x)$ with its coefficients.  The multiplicities of the roots of $f(x)\in\mathcal{P}_d$ defines a partition $\pi(f)$ of $d$. For example, if $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^d$, then $\pi(f)=(d)$, and if $f(x)$ has distinct roots, then $\pi(f)=(1^d)$.

For any partition $\sigma$ of $d$, the set
$$  \mathcal{P}_d(\sigma) := \bigl\{ f\in\mathcal{P}_d : \pi(f)=\sigma\bigr\} $$
is a quasiprojective subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^d$. (This follows from elimination theory.) For example, $\mathcal{P}_d(d)$ is a curve, while $\mathcal{P}_d(1^{d-2},2)$ is an open subset of the discriminant locus $\bigl\{f\in\mathcal{P}_d:\operatorname{Disc}(f)=0\bigr\}$.

- Do these varieties $\mathcal{P}_d(\sigma)$ have a name? My best guess was *discriminantal variety*, but that term does not seem to be in use.
- Where have these varieties been studied? Specific references would be appreciated.

Comment: I may update this later when I'm in front of a computer, but I believe the name you're looking for is _coincident root loci_. There is quite a bit of literature on these that goes back at least to Cayley's work.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi Thanks. A very logical name that I would not have been able to guess. MathSciNet has 5 articles from the 2000s with "coincident root loci" in the title, and from those I'll be able to locate further material. I'm not surprised they've been studied for a long time. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: The term _discriminantral variety_ has already been used by Gelfand, Kapranov, Zelevinski in their book "Discriminants, resultants and multidimensional determinants"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may be wrong but I think "coincident root loci" mentioned in Gjergjji's comment was coined by my coauthor Jaydeep Chipalkatti. The ideals of such varieties are in general poorly understood.

For a general study see:

1. J. Chipalkatti, ["On equations defining Coincident Root loci"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869303003363), J. Algebra **267** (2003), no. 1, 246-271.
2. J. Chipalkatti, ["Invariant equations defining coincident root loci"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00013-004-1191-z), Archiv der Math. **83** (2004), no. 5, 422-428.
3. H. Lee and B. Sturmfels, ["Duality of multiple root loci"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869315004822), J. Algebra **446** (2016), 499-526.

For particular cases, the following might be also of interest.

1. A. Abdesselam and J. Chipalkatti, ["Brill–Gordan loci, transvectants and an analogue of the Foulkes conjecture"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870806000909), Adv. Math. **208** (2007), no. 2, 491-520. It has a description of the ideal for a partition with two equal parts.
2. A. Abdesselam and J. Chipalkatti, ["The bipartite Brill-Gordan locus and angular momentum"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00031-005-1111-8), Transformation Groups **11** (2006),
   no. 3, 341-370. It has a description of the ideal for a partition with two unequal parts.
3. A. Abdesselam and J. Chipalkatti, ["On Hilbert Covariants"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/on-hilbert-covariants/080B5B7777CFA44DA20622B1598A5C0A)
   Canadian J. Math. **66** (2014), no. 1, 3-30. It has several set-theoretic systems of equations for the varieties corresponding to rectangular partitions, and a conjecture about minimal degree of generators for the ideals. This is an $SL_2$ analogue/toy version of the Foulkes-Howe conjecture.

There is also work about these varieties from a topological point of view, e.g.,
F. Napolitano,
["On some topological invariants of algebraic functions associated to the Young stratification of polynomials"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016686410300107X)
Topology Appl. **134** (2003), no. 3, 189-201.

The relation to Hurwitz stacks is studied in: J. Bertin and M. Romagny,
["Champs de Hurwitz"](http://www.numdam.org/item/MSMF_2011_2_125-126__1_0/), Mémoires SMF, no. 125-126 (2011), 219 p. See also [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701680) for the arXiv version. The relevant result is Theorem 9.16 relating coincident root loci and Hurwitz stacks of cyclic coverings of $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Also, an interesting geometric approach to these varieties is in: G. Katz ["How tangents solve algebraic equations, or a remarkable geometry of discriminant varieties"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0723086903800026), Expositiones Math. **21** (2003),
no. 3, 219-261.

Of course, this is by no means an exhaustive bibliography. There are many references I left out in this short MO post.

Comment: I phrased my comment poorly. I only meant that people have looked at the varieties for a while, perhaps under different names. Thank you for this list of references!

Comment: Thanks. I'd already found the articles by Chipalkatti after Gjergji told me the right search term. I like the terminology, but even more, I appreciate the references. For the history, Chipalkatti says in his article "We revisit an old problem in classical invariant theory...This problem is addressed for the first time (to my knowledge) by
Arthur Cayley." I'll accept your answer, since you've so kindly provided a great list of entries into the literature, which is what I was seeking. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. BTW regarding 19th century references, indeed Cayley seems to be one of the first to systematically study these varieties. Also, Hilbert computed their degrees (formula and ref are recalled in JC's first paper above).